# MySQL: Import sql file got ERROR 1064

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I went to recover my MYSQL database (contains innodb table) but I got this error:

> "ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'ÿþ-"

This is the command I used in directory where **mydatabase.sql** is located:

```
mysql -u mydbuser -p mydatabase < mydatabase.sql
```

**mydbuser** is allowed to connect to the server from **localhost** and has all grant on **mydatabase**

Anyone there had this issue and solved it?

Comment: The content of your SQL file would be interesting. But from the error it looks like you have a special characters at the beginning of that file. Try to remove that

Comment: Hi, i just solved this issue by copied my database directory to my mysql directory, database and table found in mysql prompt.

But i have new trouble, my mysql server using myisam engine, how i solve this trouble? so my web application can use that database